# Ansible win_disk_facts problem getting the drive letter

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am trying to set a share on all disks present in a windows host.  I use [`win_disk_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_disk_facts_module.html) to get all the disks present on the host, then I manage to loop trough the disks, but I cannot get the drive letter for some reason.  Not being fluent in YAML, I'm pretty sure the problem is with my syntax.

Here is the debug code:

```yaml
- name: Get disk facts
  win_disk_facts:

- name: debug
  debug:
    msg: '{{ disk.partitions.drive_letter }}'
  loop: '{{ ansible_facts.disks }}'
  loop_control:
    loop_var: disk
```

This will return the error:

> "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The
>   error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'drive_letter'

But it does exist, so it must be the way I am trying to access it.

Any pointer?

Comment: `partitions` is itself a list, whilst you are trying to access it like an object/dictionary

Comment: how is that done in yml?  The ansible doc exemples  only goes one level deep, so it uses a dot :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that `partitions` property is itself a list, whilst you are trying to access it like an object/dictionary. You can use the [`subelements` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#subelements-filter) to traverse nested key from a list of dictionaries.

I don't have a Windows machine on hand so I can't verify this is working, but mocking `ansible_facts` with my own `ansible_fact5`, here's a simplified working example:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: yes
  vars:
    ansible_fact5:
      disks:
        - guid: 1,
          partitions:
            - drive_letter: 'A'
            - drive_letter: 'B'
        - guid: 2,
          partitions:
            - drive_letter: 'C'
            - drive_letter: 'D'
  tasks:
    - name: with_subelements -> loop
      debug:
        msg: "Disk {{ item.0.guid }} - Drive {{ item.1.drive_letter }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_fact5.disks | subelements('partitions') }}"
```

`item.0` refers to each individual element within `ansible_fact5.disks`, and `item.1` refers to each individual element within `ansible_fact5.disks.$.partitions`

When you run this playbook, you'll get this output:

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yaml
...
TASK [with_subelements -> loop] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'guid': 1, 'partitions': [{'drive_letter': 'A'}, {'drive_letter': 'B'}]}, {'drive_letter': 'A'}]) => {}

MSG:

Disk 1 - Drive A
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'guid': 1, 'partitions': [{'drive_letter': 'A'}, {'drive_letter': 'B'}]}, {'drive_letter': 'B'}]) => {}

MSG:

Disk 1 - Drive B
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'guid': 2, 'partitions': [{'drive_letter': 'C'}, {'drive_letter': 'D'}]}, {'drive_letter': 'C'}]) => {}

MSG:

Disk 2 - Drive C
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'guid': 2, 'partitions': [{'drive_letter': 'C'}, {'drive_letter': 'D'}]}, {'drive_letter': 'D'}]) => {}

MSG:

Disk 2 - Drive D

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```